# How to get a JWT token from my laravel backend in angular?

Tags: angular, laravel

I'm a beginner in both frameworks, i want to use the token in the front-end so is there a way to get it from the back-end ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [JWT Documentation](https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/quick-start/)

```
 public function login()
    {
        $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

        if (! $token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }

        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
    }
```